# Express the definition of even using universal and existential quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I got a bit confused when trying to rewrite the following statement using $\forall$ and $\exists$ quantifiers:

An integer is even iff it equals double some other integer.

$\exists x\in Z(\forall y \in Z(x=2y \iff even(x)))$

"An integer" sound to me  like the statement should be universally quantified:

$\forall x\in Z(\exists y \in Z(x=2y \iff even(x)))$

which doesn't make sense, as not all integers are even.

Maybe

$\forall x\in Z(\forall y \in Z(x=2y \iff even(x)))$

is correct then? For all combinations of two integers $x$ and $y$, $x = 2y$ iff $x$ is even.

Comment: If the last one was valid, then you could take any two integers for which the statement $x = 2y \iff even(x)$ is always true. Okay, so let's take $x = 4, y = 1$. Then $x \ne 2 \cdot y$, which implies $4$ is not even...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A correct formalization of the phrase "an integer is even iff it equals double some other integer" is the following:
\begin{align}
\forall x \in \mathbb{Z} \, (\exists y \in \mathbb{Z} \, (x = 2y) \iff \textrm{even}(x))
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$
\forall x\in \mathbb Z(even(x) \iff \exists y\in \mathbb Z(2*y=x))
$$
Another way. Even numbers are all elements of set $\{2*n |n \in \mathbb Z \}$